# Why do I get ORA-00907 in my SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I have this SQL query which a partner has done for a little project at university (this is the first time we use SQL), but we get the `ora-00907` error and both of us don't know why.

I have checked the parenthesis and they seem to be ok, so the problem must be another.

```
select
    persona.nombre,
    anyo,
    t2.total
from persona join
(
    select
        t1.idPersona,
        count(produccion.anyo) as total,
        anyo 
        from
        (
            select *
            from produccion
            join pelicula
                on produccion.id = pelicula.id
        ) as pel
        join
        (
            select *
            from participa
            where idPapel = 8
        ) as t1
           on t1.idProduccion = pel.id
    )
    group by t1.idPersona
) as t2
    on persona.id = t2.idPersona
where t2.total > 2
order by t2.total desc;
```

Comment: `from (produccion join pelicula on produccion.id=pelicula.id) as pel` looks strange to me, replace it with `from produccion join pelicula on produccion.id=pelicula.id` (also `pel.id` with`production.id`)

Comment: I think I may have altered your query during the edit, but I think your parentheses are unbalanced.  In situations like yours, it can be very helpful to neatly format your query.  Often, just doing that will reveal the problem.

Comment: I count 3 opening and 4 closing brackets.

Comment: There is an extra closing parenthesis (`)`) before `group by`. Remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of nested views, which makes your query rather hard to debug. You have lots of brackets, which need to match.

Anyway this is wrong: `select t1.idPersona, count(produccion.anyo) as total, anyo`. You'll need to include `anyo` in the GROUP BY clause, which will probably change the result set you want.

```
select persona.nombre, 
       t2.anyo,
       t2.total
from persona join
        (select t1.idPersona, 
                count(produccion.anyo) as total, 
                anyo 
         from (select *
               from produccion 
                    join pelicula 
                    on produccion.id=pelicula.id) pel
               join
               (select *
                from participa
                where idPapel=8) t1
               on t1.idProduccion=pel.id
         group by t1.idPersona, t1.anyo) t2
     on persona.id=t2.idPersona
where t2.total>2
order by t2.total desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting * and doing group by on one column which is creating problem. Either you select only respective column under group by condition OR you remove group by.

```
select *
               from (produccion join pelicula on produccion.id=pelicula.id) as pel
               join
               (select *
                from participa
                where idPapel=8) as t1
               on t1.idProduccion=pel.id)
         group by t1.idPersona
```

Above code section is unallowed use of group by.

If  group by is so much needed, i would suggest you to use it later on in the end. Another option is to use analytical function and filter out rest un-wanted records in upper nesting of query which you already have.

Comment: That's because in the group by of the end I need to put all the columns that appear in the select clause of the first line, isn't it? @Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

I think your query can be simplified/corrected like this:

```
select  persona.nombre,
        anyo,
        t2.total
from    persona 
join    (
           select     par.idPersona,
                      count(produccion.anyo) as total,
                      anyo 
           from       produccion
           join       pelicula
                  on  produccion.id = pelicula.id        
           left join  participa par          
                  on  par.idProduccion = pelicula.id -- or produccion.id, 
                                                     -- this was also an error in the original query,
                                                     -- since the subquery selected both
                  and par.idPapel = 8    
           group by   t1.idPersona
           ,          anyo    -- Was missing, but it also doesn't make sense, as this is what you count, so you'll just get 1's here. What do you want with this?
       ) as t2
    on persona.id = t2.idPersona
where  t2.total > 2
order by t2.total desc;
```

Comment: What I wanted to do is to have a list of film directors who have taken part in 3 or more films in the same year with descending order (of films directed in total and in the same year) @HoneyBadger